# How to set a pixel's RGB value

Tags: image-processing, julia

So far I have this:

[image]

```
using Images, Colors
a = Array{UInt8}(5, 5, 3)
imOutput = colorim(a)
```

How do I assign three values to a pixel:

```
imOutput[1,1] =
```

Comment: `imOutput.data[1,1,:] = [1,1,1]`

Comment: @GnimucKey Thanks! Is this the same as the `data()` function that's in the documents? And how can you make the pixel a specific color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't know there is a `data()` function, i actually find the solution by doing `dump(imOutput)`:

```
Images.Image{FixedPointNumbers.UfixedBase{UInt8,8},3,Array{FixedPointNumbers.UfixedBase{UInt8,8},3}} 
  data: Array(FixedPointNumbers.UfixedBase{UInt8,8},(5,5,3)) 5x5x3 Array{FixedPointNumbers.UfixedBase{UInt8,8},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.314  0.498  0.337  0.0    0.102
 0.584  0.0    0.549  0.565  0.498
 0.337  0.0    0.102  0.212  0.0  
 0.549  0.816  0.498  0.906  0.0  
 0.102  0.584  0.0    0.545  0.188

[:, :, 2] =
 0.588  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.337  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.549  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.102  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.498  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

[:, :, 3] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
  properties: Dict{ASCIIString,Any} len 3
    colorspace: ASCIIString "RGB"
    colordim: Int64 3
    spatialorder: Array(ASCIIString,(2,)) ASCIIString["y","x"]
```

the output shows that you can use `imOutput.data` to access the data.
and yes, this is totally the same as `data()` function, take a look at this [line](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/blob/fc63fa17ee54beb482398a5b0b989fd8e838b296/src/core.jl#L560).

from the output, we can see `imOutput`'s colorspace is `RGB`, so if we have a color from `HSL`, we should convert that color into `RGB` space before we pass that color into `imOutput.data`. for example,

```
a = convert(RGB, HSL(270, 0.5, 0.5))
imOutput.data[1,1,:] = [a.r, a.g, a.b]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant (mind the dimensions for `a`)

```
a = Array{UInt8}(3,5,5)
imOutput = colorim(a)
imOutput[1,1] = RGB(0,0,0)
imOutput
```

The [tests for Images.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl/blob/82df4e626a5a279ceed44ba4b33fae32cc900590/test/core.jl#L54) helped me realize this.

Comment: Thanks - that looks backwards to me, but it certainly works!